# Draw squares with Core Graphics or include pngs?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, core-graphics

I'm making a legend for a graph that will basically look like this:

```
[ ] Line 1
[ ] Line 2
[ ] Line 3
```

The boxes on the left need to be the same color as the lines on the graph.

Anyhow, all I need to know, is whether it's faster to draw the boxes with Core Graphics or just make some pngs with GIMP for the squares and include them.

Comment: It's faster in the CPU to use CG.  It faster in re/development time to png it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use UIView for each legend and set their background color to the color you want.

Answer (score 1):

Both approaches are fast enough that it shouldn't make a difference. However, using Core Graphics has the advantage that you're a lot more flexible, e.g. when you later decide that you need additional colors. Plus, your app will be smaller, because you don't have to include the PNG files.

Answer (score 0):

Drawing boxes is a snap! I would go with Core Graphics everyday, especially since you get retina support for free.

As can be seen in this example you can do it using UIKit only classes:

```
// Setup colors
[myBoxColor setFill];
[myBoxBorderColor set];
// Setup a path for the box
UIBezierPath* path = [UIBezierBath bezierPathWithRect:rectOfTheBox];
path.lineWidth = 2;
// Draw!
[path fill];
[path stroke];
```

One warning; stroke fills using the edges of the path as the center of the line. So you will get a blurry line if you stroke a path with integral rect with a 1 point line width.

You can remedy this is you want a 1 point line for the border by doing something like this:

```
CGRect strokeRect = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rectOfTheBox, 
                                          UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.5f,0.5f,0.5f,0.5f));
UIBezierPath* path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:strokeRect];
[path stroke];
```

Answer (score 0):

On iOS, Core Graphics is quite simple to use.  In your view's `drawRect:` method, just do this to draw a square:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)frame {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1); // gray
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(10, 10, 20, 20)); // our rect is {10,10,20,20)
    // draw a line
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1, 0, 0, 1);
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, startX, startY);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, endX, endY);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Hope this helps!